# Creating an Observable using startWith from an Observable

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs5

I'm filtering an `Observable` with the input of another `Observable` - the input for the filtering comes from the user.

The filtering is done with the RxJS operator `combineLatest`. Using this means that when subscribing to this stream, no values are emitted until there has been an emission from both source Observables - I'd like the created stream to emit on creation (without any filtering), before any user input takes place.

I think I should be using the [`startWith`](http://reactivex.io) operator so the stream has an emission on creation, but I can't work out how to seed this from an Observable. Using an Observable because data comes from Firebase and is handled with `FirebaseListObservable`'s.

Below is a pieced-together version of what I'm doing currently.

```
let tagInput = document.getElementById('tags');
let tagExclusionStream = Observable
  .fromEvent(tagInput, 'input')
  .map((e: any) => createsArrayFromInput(e.target.value));

let allTags: Observable<any[]> = getAllTags();

let filteredTags = allTags
  .combineLatest(tagExclusionStream, (tags, tagExclusions) => {
     return tags.filter((tag: any) => tagExclusions.indexOf(tag.$key) == -1)
  });

// I want this to print out without needing the tagExclusionStream to emit first 
filteredTags.subscribe(tags => console.log("Tags:", tags))
```

Please let me know if my approach here is completely off/there's a better way as I'm new to RxJS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this will do the trick:

```
let filteredTags = allTags
  .combineLatest(tagExclusionStream.startWith(''), (tags, tagExclusions) => {
     return tags.filter((tag: any) => tagExclusions.indexOf(tag.$key) == -1)
  });
```

Alternatively, if you use `tagExclusionStream` in different places you can do this:

```
let tagExclusionStream = Observable
  .fromEvent(tagInput, 'input')
  .map((e: any) => createsArrayFromInput(e.target.value))
  .startWith('');
```

Comment: I like this approach - creating an emission on the stream that wouldn't otherwise emit until there is user input. This worked, so thank you for pointing this out! I had to change the parameter of startWith to be preceded with `<any>` to avoid a TypeScript error. I also changed the parameter to be `[]` vs `''` as that's what my `tagExclusionStream` emits.

Answer (score 22):

`startWith` is just using `concat` [internally](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/operators/startWith.ts#L69).
So do

```js
const startValue$ = of('start with this')

concat(startValue$, source$)
```

Or write your own operator

```ts
function startFrom<T, O extends ObservableInput<any>>(start: O): OperatorFunction<T, T | ObservedValueOf<O>> {
  return (source: Observable<T>) => concat(start, source)
}

source$.pipe(
  startFrom(startValue$)
)
```

**Make sure `startValue$` completes**

The new Observable will switch to `source$` once `startValue$` completes.
So if the Observable to start with is a long-lived Observable e.g. a `ReplaySubject` where you only care about the most recent value you have to make sure the Observable you pass in completes, e.g. with `take(1)`.

```js
const { ReplaySubject, concat, of } = rxjs;
const { take } = rxjs.operators;

const source$ = of('source-1', 'source-2')
const replay = new ReplaySubject(1)
replay.next('subject-1')
replay.next('subject-2')

const startWith$ = replay.pipe(take(1)) // <-- take one item and complete
const o$ = concat(startWith$, source$)
o$.subscribe(console.log)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/6.5.5/rxjs.umd.min.js" integrity="sha256-85uCh8dPb35sH3WK435rtYUKALbcvEQFC65eg+raeuc=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```